# Android App Development on Eclipse with ADT. Quickest way to stop process (app)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm new to Android development. When I run my app in the Java perspective I click the default Run button on the menu bar. To stop it I need to click on the DDMS perspective, click on the App in the list of names on the Devices tab, and then click on the Stop Process button.

So 3 clicks!

Is there not an easier way to do this, ideally involving one click/action?

I'm using Eclipse 3.8.1 with Android 4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there not an easier way to do this, ideally involving one click/action?

At minimum, you need to indicate the process you wish to terminate, then indicate that you wish to terminate it. You are welcome to have the Devices view in other perspectives (e.g., Java) to save your moving over to the DDMS perspective.

The only "one click/action" solution is the power button on your development machine.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

Those who find it tedious switching between perspectives to stop the program (like I did), you can view the devices windows in your current perspective by selecting

Windows > Show View > Other... > Android > Devices

from this post - [How to stop a program running under Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972699/android-how-to-stop-running-program-under-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.

Install one of those Task Killers (should never be used IRL) in your emulator. Add their widget on your Homescreen and configure it to kill your process when you click it.