# Eclipse ADT: Working but "Terminate" button greyed out...?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt, terminate

I've got Eclipse with ADT installed and running. Debugging is working over both USB and TCP/IP (WiFi) including live breakpoints. I'm a seasoned firmware/software developer, just new to Android/Java, and I'm pretty impressed so far with the development environment.

Basically, everything is fine - except that I cannot formally terminate a debug session. The Terminate button is visible in the Run menu but is greyed out. The Suspend and Disconnect icons are functional, just not Terminate. I've checked on the Debug toolbar too - same situation.

I've searched lots of places but haven't found anything that addresses a "greyed out Terminate button". Any advice?

MORE: I've also tried the "Window / Show View / Console" tip from the help system. The associated screen shot shows a Terminate button in the Console menu bar. However, no such button appears on my screen, neither red nor grey. Meanwhile, the code is running, breakpoints work... so I KNOW it's debugging. I just can't Terminate it!

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972699/android-how-to-stop-running-program-under-eclipse

Comment: try first select the app in the left section of DDMS, which will show you current visible process, then the "Terminate" button show light up.

Answer (score 7):

Just Click on the Name of the [Android Application] in the debug perspective and you stop button will be activated.