# Eclipse terminate debug button grayed out

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a follow up question to this previously asked question:

[Eclipse ADT: Working but "Terminate" button greyed out...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245281/eclipse-adt-working-but-terminate-button-greyed-out)

Like in the question above, the terminate button in Eclipse is grayed out, so like the answer is saying, I'm choosing the debug perspective, choosing the app name and then the button is enabled and I can terminate the session.

The problem is that this proccess repeats itself all the time. The button keeps graying out every time I open the debug and I have to repeat the above proccess every single time. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the Devices view to your perspective - and then you don't need to change to the Debug perspective. To add it, go to Window -> show View -> Devices

Comment: It seems like finding a way to stop the debug session instead of solving the issue itself since the terminate button is still grayed out.

Comment: I personally develop in the Debug perspective.

Comment: I will delete my answer if you want

Comment: no need since it does provide an easier way to terminate the debug session. So I might not accept it but I will give it a thumb up.

Comment: Another thing: Sometimes the Stop and Resume get lost, and I make them enabled again by double clicking inside the Debug view, on the first raw of the stack.